# Refresh browser with PHP function after Javascript & AJAX POST

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, browser

My Javascript allows user to logon to 3rd party system, returning an array of user details.  This works perfectly :)

I use JSON and AJAX to POST it to a PHP script.  This also works.

The PHP script interrogates my mySQL database, returning various details.  This works too!

However, I can only view the mySQL output in Safari's Web Inspector.  I presume I need to get the PHP script to "refresh" the browser to display the output, but cannot find how to do.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't this rather defeat the point of AJAX calls?

Comment: Thanks Elias.  You put me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do this with JavaScript.

When your ajax returns, you'll want to load that into your page.  In your success handler update a DOM element to contain the user details you're interested in.

Using jQuery:  (and very rudimentary)

**HTML:**

```
...
<div id="userLoginDetails"></div>
...
```

**JS:**

```
$.post('ajax/login.php', { username: 'john doe', password: 'blah' }, function(data) {
  $('#userLoginDetails').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to push the control from PHP:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/javascript');
    die('location.href=location.href;');
?>
```

Or even by JavaScript, after the AJAX load, in the `success` function you can include this:

```
success: function() {
    // Other Codes
    location.href=location.href
}
```

Comment: After successful AJAX request!

Answer (score 0):

The penny dropped.  All I needed was the AJAX "success" function - Duh.  Thanks for all your help.

```
    $.ajax({        
    type: "POST",
    url: "AddEdit_Interests.php",
    data: { interestsArray : result },
    success: function(data) {
         $("#lengthQuestion").fadeOut('slow'); 
         document.write(data);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Dont use `document.write`. See RC's answer